# convert vector<int> to const unique_ptr<const int[]>

Tags: c++, vector, containers, unique-ptr

how to convert/copy a vector to unique_ptr<int[]> ?

this is what I want to achieve (the vector originates in another context and will be deleted after copying to the unique_ptr. unique_ptr is of fixed length and thus can be allocated more efficiently).

```
std::vector<int> vv {1, 2, 3};

struct
    U {
        U(std::vector<int> v) { // copy constructor
            // copy vector v to unique_ptr u, HOW?
        }

        std::unique_ptr<int[]> u; 
};


U uu {vv}; // copy vector vv to unique_ptr uu, HOW?
```

i tried to make a copy constructor

```
U(std::vector<int> v) {
    u = std::make_unique<int[]>(v.size()); // OK
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), u); // error: u has no copy constructor
}
```

so, how should I construct the copy constructor?

actually and moreover, once constructed I want the unique_ptr<T[]> to be constant in both length and content, so in my case it should be

```
std::unique_ptr<int const[]> const u; // const in both length and content
```

how does the copy constructor look in both cases?

case 1) std::unique_ptr<int[]> u
case 2) std::unique_ptr<int const[]> const u

Comment: _for performance reasons, vector is not optimal_  I don't see how that's possible.  An array and a vector have the same performance characteristics.

Comment: *for performance reasons, vector is not optimal* There is no difference in performance between a `std::vector` and a `std::unique_ptr`.  Use a vector, it's the tool for the job.

Comment: A `vector` owns the storage it stores the data in. I hope you are not asking the equivalent of doing `ptr.reset(vec.data())`.

Comment: even if there was a difference you would need a lot of difference to justify copying the whole vector

Comment: Especially since there are two copies, one for the vector, and then one in the `unique_ptr`. And the error is `u.get()`, not just `u`. Basically a typo.

Comment: You really should explain what your performance concerns are. It is for sure possible to answer your question. But it seems that you have a misunderstanding about why you could have performance problems when using a `vector` compared to `unique_ptr` so this should be clearified first.

Comment: _unique_ptr is of fixed length and thus can be allocated more efficiently_  A vector can use `reserve` which will be allocated just as efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with what you are doing. First you have two copies instead of one (in the `U` constructor), then as you need to get the actual iterator on your `u`, not `u` itself.

For the const correctness, you can just have an intermediate unique pointer that allows the data to be changed.

The final code you have should look like:

```
struct U {
    U(const std::vector<int>& v) {
        auto data = std::make_unique<int[]>(v.size());
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), data.get());
        u = std::move(data);
    }

    std::unique_ptr<int const[]> u; 
};
```

To note: a vector is as efficient as your unique pointer. The data access pattern are going to be the same. The overhead is only if you push_back to it, or erase. As you are not doing any of these, just store a `const vector`.

If you wanted a `const std::unique_ptr<int const[]> u`, then you need to add a `static` method that will convert your vector into a `std::unique_ptr<int const[]>` and your constructor would take a `&&` on it and move it in `u` in the init list.

```
struct U {
    U(std::unique_ptr<int const[]>&& u)
    : u(std::move(u)) {}

    static U create(const std::vector<int>& v) {
        auto data = std::make_unique<int[]>(v.size());
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), data.get());
        std::unique_ptr<int const[]> u = std::move(data);
        return U(std::move(u));
    }

    const std::unique_ptr<int const[]> u; 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> i tried to make a copy constructor

That's not a copy constructor. That's a converting constructor.

> ```
> std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), u); // error: u has no copy constructor
> ```

The third argument of `std::copy` must be an iterator just like the first two. `std::unique_ptr` is not an iterator.

The unique pointer points to an array. A pointer is an iterator for array. So, what you need is a pointer. How to get a pointer from a unique pointer? Use `std::unique_ptr::get` member function.

You can make the constructor much more generic by accepting templated iterators (or a range) rather than a vector. As a bonus, you avoid copying twice (which can also be avoided by using a reference).

> unique_ptr is of fixed length and thus can be allocated more efficiently

There is little difference in how a vector and a dynamic array such as one managed by a unique pointer can be allocated. Even if there is some difference, copying the input vector for conversion is going to be much less efficient than not copying it.